# JavaScript fibonacci - RangeError: when base (n == 1) or (n == 0), but not if (n <= ). Why?

Tags: javascript

This works fine:

```
function fibonacci(n) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    return n;
  } else {
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
  }
}
console.log('fibonacci ' + fibonacci(7));
```

But if I replace the base with (n == 1) or (n == 0) or even (n === 1). I get a RangeError. Can somebody explain why? The funny thing is that it works with simple sum function:

```
function sumTo(n) {
 if (n == 1) {
  return n;
 } else {
  return n + sumTo2(n - 1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need both checks of `n === 1 || n === 0`, because you take the call with two values, `n - 1` and `n - 2`.

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
  if (n === 1 || n === 0) {
    return n;
  } else {
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
  }
}
console.log('fibonacci ' + fibonacci(7));
```

Comment: OK I get it :) Thanks! I take the call with two numbers.

Comment: I did some research, so I would like to add this: "A stack overflow occurs when there is a recursive function (a function that calls itself) without an exit point." source: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-the-javascript-call-stack-861e41ae61d4

Answer (score 0):

it should work for `n==1 || n==0`

```
function fibonacci(n) {
  if (n == 1 || n==0) {
    return n;
  } else {
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
  }
}
```

for `n===1` it doesnt work
because for n=2 second call will go for `n-2` which is`0` and thats what you are not handling